# How to prepend a single character to a string value in c

Tags: c

I have my code wherein I am supposed to add a character to the beginning of a string.

Here's my string and my character:

```
char array[12]="12345678"
char var="K"
```

The value of the finished array must be like this:

```
array="K12345678"
```

Currently I have written this like:

```
char temp[12]={0}
char array[12]="12345678"
char var="K"
strcpy(temp,var);
strncat(temp,array,sizeof(array));
strcpy(array,temp);
```

Comment: Any other best way to accomplish this?

Comment: char var="K"? You can not store string in a char variable. Paste the exact code you are trying.

Comment: `snprintf(temp, sizeof temp, "%c%s", var, array);`, of course you need to change `char var="K";` to `char var='K';`

Comment: I tried this snprintf(temp, sizeof temp, "%c%s", var, array); but its copying the KKKKKKKK only

Answer (score 2):

First of all notice that

```
char var="K"
```

is **not** correct. To initialize a `char` do

```
char var='K';
```

Then notice that

```
strcpy(temp,var);
```

is illegal code as `var` is not a string but a single char.

You can fix that by doing:

```
char temp[12]={0};
char array[12]="12345678";
char var='K';
temp[0] = var;  // Put the char as first character of temp
strncat(temp,array,sizeof(array));
strcpy(array,temp);
```

A better option would be `memmove` - something like:

```
// Move the current string 1 to the right (incl. the zero termination)
memmove(array+1, array, strlen(array) + 1);

// Insert the char in front
array[0] = var;
```

If you don't want to use `memmove` you can also just do a simple loop:

```
size_t i = strlen(array);
do
{
    array[i+1] = array[i];
    --i;
} while (i > 0);
array[0] = var;
```

Comment: Thank you @4386427 memmove is working as expected for me. Also by mistake i wrote K in  double quotes. Thanks everyone